# How to make an excel cell ReadOnly using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, vsto

```
Range range= (Range)this.workSheet.Cells[1,1];
range.AllowEdit = false;
```

When I set the **`AllowEdit`** property to false, a compile error will show:

> Error: Property or indexer
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.AllowEdit' cannot be assigned to
>   -- it is read only

How can I set the range of cells to be Read Only?

When I am using validation for this range I got Some exception on my CellContentChanged Event .

Here is the code which is in CellContentChanged:

```
   var updater = new Action<StyleColorItem>(
           item =>
           {
              var editedItem = _taskViewModel.TrackedItems.First(it => it.Id == item.Id); 
            // Above line I am getting the exception like "Sequence contains no matching element"
               editedItem.Update(item);'
           });
```

Comment: A excel cell can be set to `read only` only of you set it's property `Locked=True` and then set the `WorkSheet=Protected`. I don't know if it is easy to do it by C# code but you could try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to make a cell read-only in excel.

What you can do in your c# code is, define a cell that is going to be "read-only" in a variable or a list, subscribe to the SheetChange event , in the SheetChange event, if that cell gets changed, simply undo that change.

**Example**
    private List readOnlyCells = new List();

```
private void OnActiveSheetCellChange(object changedSheet, Excel.Range changedCell)
{
  if (readOnlyCells.Contains(changedCell))
      changedCell.Value = string.Empty;
      //.... YOUR CODE
```

**Update**

Another alternative is to use Data Validation:

```
changedCell.Validation.Add(Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateCustom, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, "\"\"");
```

Using it you will have less control and the cell will simply not accept any input.

Comment: In my code is saying that "XlDVType" does not exist in my namespace

Comment: try adding this using directive using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Comment: I used ur code in my application.Its restricting to edit value but  Its saying as a alert like "Some user restrict this value" and after i cancel that alert box i got some issues in my CellContentChanged event.. How can i resolve this problem now?

Comment: Well, first of all,I suggest you use the first method I suggested. And second, please define "some issues"

Comment: you will have to figure out the rest of the logic yourself :)

Comment: Thank you so much Anima! Its working! Thanks for your helpful code

Comment: I have one doubt in this code. Can we add our own error message to this validation? and Can you please explain me about the param "\"\""? What is the use of this parameter? Is that required must?

Comment: I'm not sure about displaying your own error message, the param "\"\"" basically is an empty string ""

Comment: Can we add Type.Missing instead of giving as empty string at the last param?

Comment: I tried that Which will show en error message like "Data May exist in the sheet(s) selected for deletion.To permenantly delete the data,Press Delete" .But Your code will give the result which I expect. Apart from This, I have to say Thanks to you for sharing more information with me for a long time. Thanks for responding each and every clarification. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be done by setting the `Locked` property to true, and protecting the worksheet.

```
range.Locked = true;
this.workSheet.Protect(Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                       true,
                       Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                       Type.Missing);
```

Comment: can we give first Worksheet.Protect(...) and Second we can give Range.locked=true?