# Disable cell in excel sheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, excel-interop

I am using interop to create excel sheet and storing my datatable in it and opening it for user. There are some columns which I don't want the user to edit. Can I make a particular cell disabled while exporting the excel sheet?

Following is my code

```
Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(Server.MapPath("UploadedExcel/" + lblTestCode.Text.Trim() + ".xls"));

        FieldInfo myf = typeof(TEST).GetField("abcd");
        foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
        {
            //Add a new worksheet to workbook with the Datatable name
            Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add();
           // excelWorkSheet.Name = "Sheet1";

            for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;




            }

            for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < table.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    excelWorkSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();



                }
            }
        }

        excelWorkBook.Save();
        excelWorkBook.Close();
        excelApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trick: Open Excel > Developer Toolbar > Record Macro > select/highlight range > then choose FormatCells:

[image]

Change backcolor of the cells to grey to indicate they're disabled.

Stop the Macro from recording on the Developer Toolbar.

Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>  to go into VBA Editor and look at the code in Module 1.

Simply convert that code to C# - it is almost the exact same Object Model in C# as it is with VB.

Comment: Can you provide me with some code, as i am totally new to intero. Thanks

Comment: Sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582336/how-to-make-an-excel-cell-readonly-using-c  The reason I was showing you this technique is so you know how to create code (for any Excel VSTO task) by doing it manually in Excel and converting the VBA to C#.